# node_modules does not provide an export named 'Ref' on Vue.js component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm having a weird error. On a component I have, Ref is working correctly.
On a component I've just created, id doesn't. I'm calling it the same way on both.

```
import { Ref } from 'vue';

const isOpen = ref(false);
```

Giving the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=f65e1616' does not provide an export named 'Ref'

I've tried running "npm run build" again, with the following error:

> Non-existent export 'Ref' is imported from
> node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js

I don't really know what could be causing this. I work on this project on 2 different computers and I've cloned it a few days ago. I haven't encountered any issues until now

Comment: case matters , so `ref` instead of `Ref` :)

Comment: I used autocomplete and it was capitalized...this is such a dumb error that I've made..thank you, Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your import

Try this

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
```

You can see the documentation of [Vue.js (template refs)](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue in the future, for some reason when writing "import ref" your code editor may wrongly autocomplete it with capitalized `{ Ref }` instead of the right `{ ref }`